# CNN training loss stuck at values between 51-60

Tags: python, pandas, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to create my first CNN to predict apartment prices. The problem is that after 1-5 epochs loss value is stuck and doesn't decrease, only increasing a little and then decreasing again. Thanks in advance)

```
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Dense, BatchNormalization, Flatten
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.models import Sequential

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from PIL import Image
import pandas as pd

train_data_df = pd.read_excel('train_data_cnn.xlsx')
test_data_df = pd.read_excel('test_data_cnn.xlsx')

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_data = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=train_data_df, x_col='filepath', y_col='price', class_mode='raw', directory=r'C:\Users\Kojimba\PycharmProjects\DeepEval\CNN', batch_size=20)
test_data = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=train_data_df, x_col='filepath', y_col='price', class_mode='raw', directory=r'C:\Users\Kojimba\PycharmProjects\DeepEval\CNN', batch_size=20)

model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(32, kernel_size=32, strides=(2,2), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(256, 256, 3), data_format='channels_last'),
    #BatchNormalization(),
    MaxPool2D(strides=2),
    Conv2D(128, kernel_size=64, strides=(4,4), padding='same', activation='relu'),
    #BatchNormalization(),
    MaxPool2D(),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(8, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='random_normal', bias_initializer='zeros'),
    Dense(8, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='random_normal', bias_initializer='zeros'),
    Dense(1, activation='linear', kernel_initializer='random_normal', bias_initializer='zeros')
])

model.compile(Adam(lr=0.01, beta_1=0.98, beta_2=0.999), loss='mean_absolute_percentage_error')
model.summary()

model.fit_generator(train_data, steps_per_epoch=24, epochs=100)

model.evaluate_generator(test_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your last dense layer has one output. Is that intended?
If you have more than two classes you want your last dense layer to have the number of classes as output.

Other than that have you tried decreasing your lr? 
It looks high.
You could also try to add a dropout layer after your Conv2D.
Something like "Dropout(0.2)"

Comment: Yeah, that last layer is intended since its a regression model, kind of. If I use lower lr, even like 0.001, it will take forever to get through the first epoch, not to mention the next one and so on. Tried dropout - it helps to even out the loss, but it still does not go below 51

Comment: how long is forever? Do you run it on cpu or gpu?

Comment: it takes like 2 minutes for an epoch. I run the training on a cpu

Comment: If you post the data I can run your model and see what results I get. Two minutes is not much time. You should reduce the number of epoch instead. When using too high learning rate you can risk to get stuck in a local min/max. Therefore it is better to use a low learnig rate